# How to check if string contains a certain character?

Tags: swift

I've been trying to find this but I can't. I have the code:

```
func ayylmao(vorno: String){
    if (vorno.(WHATEVER THE FUNCTION FOR FINDING A STRING GOES HERE)("a", "e", "i", "o", "u"))
    {
        print("Input Includes vowels")
    }
}
```

but right at the `if` statement I can't find anything to check if the characters are in the string.

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
let s = "hello"
let ok = s.characters.contains {"aeiou".characters.contains($0)} // true
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest two implementations:

```
func numberOfVowelsIn(_ string: String) -> Int {

    let vowels: [Character] = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "y",  "A", "E", "I", "O", "U", "Y"]
    return string.reduce(0, { $0 + (vowels.contains($1) ? 1 : 0) })
}


numberOfVowelsIn("hello my friend") //returns 5.
```

... and the second one with this code snippet hereafter to reach your goal:

```
let isVowel: (Character) -> Bool = { "aeiouyAEIOUY".contains($0) }

isVowel("B")  //returns 'false'.
isVowel("a")  //returns 'true'.
isVowel("U")  //returns 'true'.
```